# Using Yarn in Sage Wordpress Starter Template

Tags: webpack, yarnpkg, roots-sage

Hello I recently started using sage again after a long time and a lot of things seem to have changed for me.  I had to install yarn but when I tried running the command `yarn run build` I got:

```
λ yarn run build
yarn run v0.20.3
$ webpack --progress --config assets/build/webpack.config.js
F:\www\xxxxxx\wp-content\themes\23022017\node_modules\copy-globs-webpack-plugin\index.js:101
const { promisify } = __webpack_require__(0);
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\www\xxxxxx\wp-content\themes\23022017\assets\build\webpack.config.js:10:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Now I have already successfully run the following commands in my terminal:

```
composer self-update
composer update
npm install
yarn
```

I am new to yarn and webpack so I can't even begin to understand what I'm doing wrong here or how to fix it.

**OS:** Windows 10

**NodeJS:** 4.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved here:
https://github.com/roots/sage/issues/1843

Looks like the issue was with my NodeJS version.